# Best way to authenticate Box content account

Tags: box

I am new to Box.com API and creating an application to connect to Box account.
I am using developer toke for testing as below:

```
 BoxAPIConnection api = new BoxAPIConnection(DEVELOPER_TOKEN);

 BoxUser.Info userInfo = BoxUser.getCurrentUser(api).getInfo();
```

However, i am confused which is the best and recommended way to use it for production

Answer (score 0):

The Box developer token is designed for testing purposes.

The OAuth process is designed to be used with Standard Box Users (Managed Users). The JWT auth process is designed to be used with App Users.